# Raster Operations (ROP) in WebGL (no glLogicOp)

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

**Question:**

Using WebGL, what is the most efficient way I can draw a bitmap on the offscreen buffer given that a raster operation must be performed for every pixel/fragment? Raster operations may vary between draw calls.

**Context:**

As part of the application I am developing, I have to develop a function used to copy a bitmap onto a destination buffer. The bitmap can be smaller than the canvas and is placed using offsets for the X and Y co-ordinates. Also, given a ROP code, a raster operation can be performed when copying the bitmap. The full list of ROPs can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183369(v=vs.85).aspx).

In OpenGL ES 1.x, there was a function called glLogicOp() which would perform the required binary operations when drawing. However, since WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, this function does not exist. I cannot yet think of a straight forward way to solve this problem. I have a few ideas but I am not as yet confident they will offer optimal performance.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Perform the ROPs in Javascript by keeping a typed array with the colour data for the offscreen buffer. This however would rely on the CPU to compute the ROP for each pixel. On draw I would upload the offscreen data to a texture and draw it on the offscreen buffer using a simple shader.
2. Use the ping-pong texture technique described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/webgl_fundamentals/?redirect_from_locale=de#toc-webglimageprocessingcontinued). Having 2 textures I could sample from one and write on the other, however, I would be forced to draw the whole offscreen buffer on every draw call, even when the bitmap to be drawn covers only a small fraction of the canvas. A possible optimization would be to switch the textures only when an ROP dependent on the destination pixel is used.
3. Use readPixels() to read data from the offscreen buffer before a draw call requiring an ROP dependent on the destination pixel. The data of the pixels on which the bitmap will be drawn is read, uploaded to a texture and passed to the shader together with the bitmap itself to be used for sampling. The readPixels function however is said to be one of the slowest WebGL functions since it requires synchronization between the CPU and GPU.

**EDIT**

Using the ping post texture technique, I think I will have to draw the whole screen every time since, for every drawing, in order to sample the destination pixel correctly I would need a representation of the current offscreen (screen before drawing). Unless I draw the whole screen every time, both textures would only represent alternate drawings rather than the real offscreen image.

It is easier to show this visually but consider this example:

1) I draw a rectangle on the left half of the screen with the first draw call having tex1 as sampling source and tex2 as drawing destination.

2) I draw rectangle on the right half of the screen with the second draw call having tex2 as sampling source and tex1 as drawing destination.

3) When I try to draw a horizontal line across the whole screen on the next draw call, since tex1 (source) does not contain the rectangle drawn in the first draw call, sampling from the left part of the screen would result in wrong colors of destination pixels.

Comment: I'd use the ping pong texture technique. It will or should be orders of magnitude faster than either JS or readpixels. I don't really understand why you need to draw the entire thing if the image only covers a small portion of the canvas but even so if you do it will be fast.

Comment: Yeah I also think that the ping pong texture technique is the most promising so far.

Comment: @gman I edited the question to clarify why I believe I'll need to draw the entire thing every time. I still haven't started the implementation so there might be something I missed out at this stage.